# How to resolve 'The syntax for 'YTD' is Incorrect' error in DAX

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I'm getting error: 'The syntax for 'YTD' is incorrect.' in my DAX query. How to solve this?

[image]

Help me in clarifying the error in the DAX formula so I can make up the mistakes in which part.

Comment: Although YTD is not a reserved key word, it seems you can not declare a variable name with YTD. try to add some suffix or prefix to check the issue solve or not.

Answer (score 0):

1. Try to rename this 'YTD' variable.
2. I see that your 'Summarized'[YTD] column has an error. Try to fix it.